# Possible Virus? CPU usage always 100% and Can't Connect to SENS

Tags: windows-7, virus, cpu-usage

I've had this error a while and I keep looking but can't find a solution.

Problems:
- Every time I start my computer it 'Cannot connect to system event notification service'. This means non admin users cant log in and I guess a number of other issues I'm unaware of. 
- My CPU performance according to Task Mgr is always 100%. THis can't be right. (Although not in safe mode)
- Also seems to have defaulted my taskbar to Windows classic. And I cant seem to change it back to Aero.

Attempted Solutions:
- So far I've installed malwarebytes/spybot and antivirus(avast). 
- I've done a system restore to before the time it started.

I'm totally stumped. I think either its a complex virus, I've missed something obvious or its a Windows Update or something.

Currently running Windows 7 (home premium). Any advice would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: Please do the following three things: 1) Use the task manager to see which task is using 100% CPU. (Add that information to the post). 2). Check the eventmanager for error (start, run, `eventvwr.msc`). If there are obvious errors, add then to the post.  3) Dragonlord alreaxdy linked to the anti-virus post. One key point in it is **not to boot** from a suspect system in order to clean it. Use one of the liveCD methods.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same saturation problem on my HP Pavilion DV6 and found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-100-cpu-usage-on-h-p-dv6/af69e90b-8060-4040-a81d-8eea6fc3b4bd?page=1&tm=1315612602363#footer) answer that worked perfectly for me..

> Windows 7 100% CPU usage on H-P Dv6
>
> Anyone experiencing maxed CPU usage by "search protocol host" and/or
>   "permon", "indexing" on a H-P laptop, I suggest returning "Power
>   Management" to "HP Recommended". It seems to cause some "loop" or
>   conflict in the HP software. It is a simple fix, drove me crazy for
>   weeks. But I have since duplicated the 100% cpu usage by another
>   (foolish) attempt to manually manage the power settings. Hope this
>   helps some of you.

Answer (score 2):

What process in task manager is using all the CPU cycles?

Or, open a run command and type in

resmon

this will open a resource monitor, you can see what is hogging cpu cycles.

Comment: According to resmon PresentationFontCache.exe is using 75-80% of my CPU.  FontCache3.0.0.0 is also using 50-65% of my services.

Comment: i found this which is a temporary solution i think. doesnt seem like the best thing to do..   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2e47b80a-1423-466f-873a-8536a64ebe3c

Comment: Sounds like the font cache was corrupted. Looks like a proper fix to me, be sure to re-enable the Service.

Comment: So that solved the fontcache issue. But I seem to be getting blue screen errors and it running slowly. There was a wmdnetwrk.exe running. I have changed that service to disabled. All these things are seemingly randomly started. Is this a dodgy build of Windows 7? It's 7600.

Comment: Did these problems start suddenly?

Comment: yep. they seemed to start out of nowhere. and get worse. im now wondering whether its a hardware issue. Although I did have a virus before this started - which was cleared out (seemingly) successfully.

Comment: When in doubt, back up important data and reinstall clean, sometimes damage done by malware is hard to correct.

Comment: you mean reinstall windows? start from scratch kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is easier than trying to figure out how to correct the damage.

Comment: Aye. Easier, and safer. **Never** trust a seemingly cleaned laptop with your important data. E.g. never use it for on-line shopping (amazon etc), internet banking, ..., .... Make a backup of all important data. Do a clean reinstallation and make sure all updates are installed. Then scan your backupped data before restoring it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Spy-bot from download.com
2. Check your computer for virus.
3. Go to `Start Menu` type services in the search box.
4. Click `Properties` on `UPnP Device Host` and disable start up.

Second option is searching system configuration on the `Start Menu`, start up sisabling all start up the start up items or if it's still not working then change your battery.

Comment: How can this be related to batteries or the UPnP service?